# reboot and select proper boot device

Tags: windows-xp

My old computer his hard drive has crashed a week ago. Ordered a new IDE hard drive. Installed the hard drive. Started the computer, inserted windows xp installation cd. Restarted computer. Set boot device to cd-rom drive. Restarted computer again. Waited untill setup should start, but instead I'm getting "reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device.".

cd is a bootable disk, so I'm not sure what is happening here. I tried also with my vista bootable cd as test and I'm getting the same message.

Any ideas on how to solve this? It's the first time I'm getting this when installing to a new hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Are your drives all being detected in the BIOS properly? It is quite often the case that new IDE drives are preconfigured to cable-select. This will causes a problem if there's another device on the same IDE channel that's not CS.